# Why are the tracks to Van Halen's "Diver Down" shown out of order?

Tags: van-halen

I recently purchased a used copy of [Diver Down (1982)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diver_Down) by Van Halen on Vinyl. Catalog number [BSK 3677](https://www.discogs.com/Van-Halen-Diver-Down/release/4098189). I noticed that the tracks are shown out of order on the back cover.

Was this a misprint or is there some other reason?

---

## Track Listing

**Back Cover order (italicized tracks are shown in the wrong order):**

- (A1) Where Have All the Good Times Gone
- *(B2/B3) Little Guitars*
- *(A2) Hang 'em High*
- (A4) Secrets
- (A5) Intruder
- (A6) (Oh) Pretty Woman
- *(B4) Big Bad Bill (Is Sweet William Now)*
- *(B1) Dancing in the Street*
- *(A3) Cathedral*
- *(B6) Happy Trails*
- *(B5) The Full Bug*

**Actual order:**

Side A -

- Where Have All the Good Times Gone
- Hang 'Em High
- Cathedral
- Secrets
- Intruder
- (Oh) Pretty Woman

Side B -

- Dancing in the Street
- Little Guitars (intro)
- Little Guitars
- Big Bad Bill (Is Sweet William Now)
- The Full Bug
- Happy Trails

---

## Images

**Back Cover**
[image]

**Side A**
[image]

**Side B**
[image]

Comment: Nice question, I've been checkin online, and I've found no mention of this... Note that on recent CD releases, this is corrected.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah in fact the first thing I did when I noticed was checked my CD sleeve. I know the track order by memory from repeated plays :) And every track listing I've found online shows the correct order, but no mention of the incorrectly ordered list.

Comment: The early LP versions have the incorrect order on their back, but no one seem to have ever worried about that...